# Angular 6: Prevent Browser Tooltip to show HTML tags in "innerHtml"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

A template in my angular application uses the following code:

```
...
<span [innerHtml]="textVar"></span>
...
```

Because the desired text requires special dynamically style applied on some characters/string position, it has to be formatted. The textVar variable is created with the following code:

```
...
var textVar = someString.bold() + "&#160" + anotherString;
...
```

The text is displayed proper with the text bold und with some tab space in between. The problem is that if you hover with the mouse over the text, the tooltip shows the text with html tags which looks like this:

```
<b>someString</b>&#160anotherString
```

But I want the tooltip to remove the html tags in the tooltip-text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip behavior of a span is controlled by the title attribute. You could try to set this title attribute to parsed value of your **`textVar`**. Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42254787/10353987) we could utilize [**`DOMParser`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to help us get the parsed html. Consider the following simplified example:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  textVar = '<b>someString</b>&#160anotherString'

  parsedText(text) {
    const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    '<!doctype html><body>' + text,
    'text/html');
    const decodedString = dom.body.textContent;
    return decodedString;
  }
}
```

And the component template looking like this:

```
<span [title]="parsedText(textVar)" [innerHtml]="textVar"></span>
```

See this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elrv9q) for a working example.

Comment: Hey, this looks like a security vulnerability to me, because you are dynamically constructing a parametised DOM object outside of the protection of Angular's sanitisation and not sanitising/escaping the text input.

Comment: Actually, it should be ok because the `innerHTML` binding will pass this into Angular's internal security checks.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
var textVar: string = `${someString.bold()} ${anotherString}`;
```

If you definitely need to use the HTML entity code: "&#160", then use:

```
var textVar: string = `${someString.bold()}&#160${anotherString}`;
```